# Not Able to Open Login Page TP LINK TL MR 3220

Tags: localhost

I forgot the ip address of my router. I reset the router. then i'm not able to open the login page. In my device Default Ip is 192.168.0.1 Username is admin and Password also admin. Ho do i open my login page

Comment: Assuming you are on Windows Start>RUN>CMD Intro then tipe IPCONFIG and search the Default Gateway, use that IP to connect to Web Setup with your favorite Browser like Mozilla IE....

Answer (score 0):

Start > Run > cmd > enter > ipconfig.  "Default Gateway" is the IP of your router.  Paste that into a web browser and it should let you in.

According to the [Userr Guide](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/20111616204111.pdf) for your router, this address will most likely be http://192.168.1.1 (see page 8-9)

Your username and password are most likely to be admin (all lower case - see page 10)